# Not receiving GTalk audio/video calls in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, gmail, google-talk

I'm using a system based on Ubuntu 14.04.

Recently a mate wanted to call me via GTalk. He is using the Gmail web interface, I - Pidgin. No popup about the call was shown.

Why?